# How to activate validation error when related input is null

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Below is the html i use

```
    <div id="my_page">
<div>
    <input type="text" id="destination_name" name="destination_name" value="Paris, France"/>
</div> 
<div>   
<input type="hidden" id="destination_code" name="destination_code" value=""/>
</div>
    </div>
```

Below is the validation rules

```
$('#my_page').validate({

    rules:{
         destination_name:{ required:true }
        }
});
```

How to activate error in 'destination_name' if 'destination_code' value is null

Comment: You'll have to do a better job explaining what you want.  Do you want `destination_name` to only be "required" when there is a value in `destination_code`?

Comment: You can't have `#my_page` as what is being validated, it has to be a form.  So...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing a function that returns false if destination_code is false. 
Sample code that I found in the [documentation section](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).

```
$(".selector").validate({
  rules: {
    contact: {
      required: true,
      email: {
        depends: function(element) {
          return $("#contactform_email:checked")
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```